# how Add "{installation home}/bin" to your PATH environment variable so that you can start Android Studio from any directory

Tags: android, ubuntu-20.04

I have download the android-studio `android-studio-ide-202.7351085-linux.tar.gz` file from `develop.android.com` and I have extracted this file to `/opt/android-studio` folder so that the android studio software should be installed on `root` directory. I don't want to install it in `/home/Downloads` directory. but I have not shown any software icon on my app bar and search bar. I want to know why and I also want to set path environment variable for run/start the android studio from any directory.

as it mentioned in `install_linux.tar`  the instruction is `3` and `4`.

> `3. [OPTIONAL] Add "{installation home}/bin" to your PATH environment variable so that you can start Android Studio from any directory.`
>
> `4. [OPTIONAL] To adjust the value of the JVM heap size, create a file studio.vmoptions (or studio64.vmoptions if using a 64-bit JDK) in the configuration directory and set the -Xms and -Xmx parameters. To see how to do this, you can reference the vmoptions file under "{installation home}/bin" as a model but do not modify it, add your options to the new file.`

my purpose of installing android-studio is for learning app development in flutter.

Comment: add in your shell configuration file something like `export PATH=YOUR_PATH:$PATH` where YOUR_PATH is the path to the `studio` file's folder

Answer (score 7):

## Short answer:

1. Go to your home directory.
2. Type `ls -a`
3. You should see file named `.bashrc` *(perhaps you will see file named `.zshrc` insead - then replace `.bashrc` with `.zshrc`)*
4. Type `nano .bashrc`
5. Add this line to the end of file: `export PATH=/path/to/your/instalation/directory/android-studio/bin:$PATH`
6. Press CTRL+s, then CTRL+x
7. Reload with `source ~/.bashrc`

## Long answer:

I had the same problem and I found this site https://linuxhint.com/add-directory-to-path-linux/, where is everything explained to details. I would recommend reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Tip:
For Kali linux add file (export PATH=/path/to/your/instalation/directory/android-studio/bin:$PATH) to .zshrc instead of .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler method.

On the android studio Menu Bar press `Tools` and then `Create Desktop Entry`